# Regex that matches a string only with question marks

Tags: regex, escaping

How could I write a regex that will match a string containing only question marks

"???"  > true

"????" > true

"? "    > true

"?a?"  > false

"?a"   > false

Thanks in advance !

Edit:
2 cases I missed:

"? " > true

"??  ? ?" > true

Comment: Shoudn't this `"?" > false` be true? or you are trying to invalidate single `?` mark?

Comment: `"?" > false` at the end looks like a mistake. You have that both false and true.

Comment: I noticed further, `"?" > true` is also there. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Yogendra Singh,@dan1111: Ups, sorry, you are right  guys, "?" should be TRUE

Comment: I just update the description, removed the wrong example and added 2 missing examples

Comment: What language are you using your regex in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that the string can contain spaces (as per the edit), the correct regex is

```
^[ ?]*[?][ ?]*$
```

This allows for any number of spaces and question marks and guarantees that at least one question mark is present.

Answer (score 8):

That would be as simple as this:

```
^[?]+$
```

The expression requires that the string from the start `^` to the end `$` consisted of question marks `[?]` (square brackets prevent interpretation as meta-character) repeated one or more times `+`.

Comment: Except you need at least two question marks, given that "?" should return false. But yeah, really simple regexp.

Comment: @John That's strange: line 3 says `true`, but the last line says `false` for a single question mark!

Comment: @John, that appears to be a mistake in the question, as `"?"` was listed as returning both true and false.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a better idea to escape the question mark (as I always escape all symbols):

```
^\?+$
```

You don't need a square bracket either.

Comment: *I always escape all symbols*--really a better rule is to escape the symbols that need escaping.  As the ? does in your example.

Comment: @dan1111 In regex, if you escape anything that is not a letter or a digit, it will consider it as an escaped symbol, and will not interpret it as anything else. This is good for compatibility through different regex engines.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?=\s*\?)[?\s]+$/
```

An Explanation:

```
^
```

Match the beginning of the string

```
(?= ... )
```

Lookahead, a zero-width assertion about what's coming up in the string, here used to assert:

```
 \s*
```

any amount of white space, followed by:

```
\?
```

A literal question mark.  Ensuring there's at least one question mark in the string.

```
[?\s]
```

Match a question mark, or whitespace.

```
+
```

One or more times.

```
$
```

Match the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex as `^\\?+$`

```
    String regex = "^\\?+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("?").find());//prints true
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("??").find());//prints true
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("????").find());//prints true
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("?a?").find());//prints false
    System.out.println(pattern.matcher("?a").find());//prints false
```